# Live Reload not working (WIN7)

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext2, livereload

I have the windows application installed, Live Reload extension for chrome and i'm using Sublime Text with Live Refresh and Live Reload plugins. For some reason any HTML doc i edit on sublime text is not auto updating on chrome. The extension is stuck on "Live Reload is connecting" when i enable it. What exactly am i missing, do i need to setup a local web server   or something like that?

Comment: I never got LiveReload to work. If you're developing strictly locally, I recommend checking out [Tincr](http://tin.cr/).

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be that you did not add the folder that contains your HTML document to the LiveReload windows application so that it can monitor for changes to the file.

If you open up the LiveReload app, it should have a list of site folders. Try adding your test project's folder to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you load from local file it does work you must runt the local file through a web server e.g python -m http.server in the folder your .html exists otherwise the option match to local file never appears and then you can have the save and reload functionality. 
I mention it because I hadn't found the problem through reading the post